# Updated code not reflecting after deployment Angular 4

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, command-line-interface

We hosted our angular application in IIS. We are facing one wired issue after deployment, once we deploy the code sometime updated HTML(index.html) is not being served, rather we are getting response of the old html and old HTML has reference of old java-script file and those are not present in server after recent deployment and for that reason application breaks.

For our application any request goes through Apache reverse Proxy then IIS.

We followed below steps but nothing solved the issue:
1. Restart IIS
2. Restart Apache service
3. Adding no cache in HTML header
4. Clear cache of browser and then access application
5. Added no cache configuration in IIS Web.config.

Comment: Anyone faced same issue?

Answer (score 0):

check if Angular builds unique hashes [see this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10641) or maybe when app update you replace older build files,in this case having unique hashes older are still there